# calculator program PHP

Tags: php, variables, calculator, calculated-columns

I have tried to make simple calculator program with php, but my code is not working.

```
<html>
<body>
<?php 
    $a = "";
    $b = "";
    $c = "";
    $jumlah = $a*$b+$c;

    if (!empty($_POST['a']))
    {
        $a =$_POST['a'];
        $b =$_POST ['b'];
        $c = $_POST['c'];
    }
?>

<Table>
    <tr>
        <td>Harga</td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $a; ?>"name="Harga"/>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Banyak Barang</td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $b; ?>" name="Harga" />
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Biaya Kirim</td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $c; ?>" name="Harga"/>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Total</td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $jumlah; ?>" name="Harga"/>
        </td>
    </tr>
    </tr>
</table> 
</body>
</html>
```

There is no error, my program just cannot show the calculated variable `a*b/c`

Comment: Well, obviously `""*""+""` = `nothing at all`. You're assigning your variables *after* you perform the calculation. So it's not very surprising you don't see anything...

Comment: I can't even see a submit button here...

Comment: There is a dangling `</tr>` tag.

Comment: i just want to put calculate number automatically on total field,so i need  submit button or form

Comment: [`Consult my answer - click here`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22561358/) I have outlined/explained the errors in your code. @Rookie

Answer (score 1):

Move:

```
$jumlah = $a*$b+$c;
```

To After:

```
   $c = $_POST['c'];
}
$jumlah = $a*$b+$c;
```

If you don't have a submit button, add one:

```
<input type="submit" value="calculate" />
```

Answer (score 1):

You seem to think PHP can time travel:

```
   $a = "";   <--- string
   $b = "";   <--- string
   $c = "";   <--- string
   $jumlah = $a*$b+$c;    <--- "string * string + string"
```

and then **AFTER** this horrible string mangling, you FINALLY start getting some values into those variables:

```
              if (!empty($_POST['a']))
               {
                 $a =$_POST['a'];
```

but by the time this particular code runs, `$jumlah` is already defined, and PHP does **NOT** time travel and retroactive change its value.

Comment: i still dont understand,can you give me example

Answer (score 1):

Move the calculation line to below the lines where you've assigned the variables. So change the php to:

```
<?php 
 $a = "";
 $b = "";
 $c = "";

 if (!empty($_POST['a']))
 {
      $a =$_POST['a'];
      $b =$_POST ['b'];
      $c = $_POST['c'];
 }
 $jumlah = $a*$b+$c;

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here your mini calculator in a ... mini script. :-)
Call it calc.php

```
<form action="./calc.php" onsubmit="" method="post">   
<b>Enter your data: </b>
<br> 
NR 1<input type="text" name="a"><br>
NR 2<input type="text" name="b"><br>
NR 3<input type="text" name="c"><br>
<br> 
<input type="submit" value="Calculate">
</form>
<p style="color:red;">
<?php 
if (!empty($_POST['a']))                   {
$jumlah = $_POST['a']+$_POST['b']+$_POST['c'];   
echo "Your answer= <b>".$jumlah."</b>"; 
}
?></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a few issues with your (*posted*) code, let me point them out to you:

The `<form></form>` tags and a submit button (*for instance*) are missing which are required when using form elements.

Another problem is that the named input elements do not match.

For example:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $a; ?>"name="Harga"/>
```

which should be:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $a; ?>"name="a"/>
```

and

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $b; ?>" name="Harga" />
```

which should be:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $b; ?>" name="b" />
```

and

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $c; ?>" name="Harga"/>
```

which should be:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $c; ?>" name="c"/>
```

Since the form is being called by: (*respectively*)

```
$a =$_POST['a']; // you presently have name="Harga" as a reference to
$b =$_POST ['b']; // you presently have name="Harga" as a reference to
$c = $_POST['c']; // you presently have name="Harga" as a reference to
```

Use this: (tested)

```
<html>
<body>
<?php

$a = "";
$b = "";
$c = "";

if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    if (!empty($_POST['a']))
    {
        $a =$_POST['a'];
        $b =$_POST ['b'];
        $c = $_POST['c'];
$jumlah = $a*$b+$c;
echo $jumlah;
    }
}
?>

<form action="" method="post">
<Table>
    <tr>
        <td>Harga</td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $a; ?>"name="a"/>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Banyak Barang</td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $b; ?>" name="b" />
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Biaya Kirim</td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $c; ?>" name="c"/>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Total</td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $jumlah; ?>" name="Harga"/>

        </td>
    </tr>
    </tr>
</table> 

<br><br>
    <input type="submit" class="form-control" name="submit"/>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```